# How to disable all built-in modules in JBoss AS 7.1?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

From time to time I get exceptions like MethodNotFoundException and ClassNotFoundException when deploying my web application to a JBoss AS 7.1 server. The reason for this is that JBoss has its own built-in modules which it prefers over libraries in my own war. I know that I can selectively exclude modules with the jboss-deployment-structure.xml, but I rather just not think about it and have it work exactly as it would when deploying it to, for example, Jetty.

Is it possible to configure JBoss to not provide any modules?

What are the use cases for using built-in modules? In my opinion, the duplicate libraries I would have to provide when deploying multiple war's doesn't outweigh the disadvantage of having possible different behavior in comparison to the environment in which I'm running my automated tests. I must be missing a vital advantage.

Comment: Your server isn't going to do a whole lot if you disable all modules.

Comment: I guess I should've been more subtle. Does the rest of my question make any sense? I'm looking to minimize the errors that occur because of differences between my testing environment and 'normal' environment. Of course, I could setup the same environment and keep it in sync, but I would rather disable some modules, because I don't see the benefit of having them there.

Comment: The easiest thing is to not include modules that the server provides. Otherwise you have to use the jboss-deployment-structure.xml

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins "The easiest thing is to not include modules that the server provides" - well, just to give an example, if your application uses a different version of Hibernate than the one which comes with JBoss AS7, you should not use this option of course.

Comment: Well that's kind of the point of Java EE though. You write code to a specification rather than an implementation. The vendors are responsible for providing an implementation that works correctly with the API.